# How to hange background color of rows based on displayed value?

Tags: html, css

I need to change the background color of an entire table row depending of the value displayed. If the value `notas`

- is < 38 then red,
- if is ==38 then blue and
- all the rest are green.

I need to do it using CSS only. All the solutions I tried erase the information displayed.

```
<table class="wp-table" id="posts">
    <tr> 
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nota Original </th>
        <th>Nota Redondeada</th>
    </tr>  
</table>
<script>
    const notas = [38,43,99,97,29,29,0, 100,40,41,42,43, 44,45,37,39, ];
    const notasid = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

    let notasr = notas.map((num) => {
        const remainder = num % 5;
        if (num< 38) {   
            return num;
        } else if (remainder >= 3) {
            num+=5-remainder
        };
        return num;
    })

    var t = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
        var tr = "<tr>";
        tr += "<td>"+notasid[i]+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>"+notas[i]+"</td>";
        tr += "<td>"+notasr[i]+"</td>";
        tr += "</tr>";
        t += tr;
    }
    document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML += t;
</script>
```

Comment: _I need to do it with css_ => I don't believe you can do it with `CSS`, but you can implement code in `Javascript` to do that, with some changes on the loop where you create the rows.

Comment: I think it's *technically* possible to use CSS, but I agree-- using JavaScript is a much better solution.

Comment: Yeah i know that its impossible using just css, i just need to do something like giving a class for each statement and then in css set the background color, but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

In this situation will be more issue to add red class for all items < 38 and do them red via CSS. You cannot cover values range via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
if (notas[i] < 38) {
var tr = "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>"+notasid[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td style='backgroud: red;'>"+notas[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+notasr[i]+"</td>";
tr += "</tr>";
t += tr; 
}
  if (notas[i] === 38) {
var tr = "<tr>";
tr += "<td>"+notasid[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td style='backgroud: blue ;'>"+notas[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+notasr[i]+"</td>";
tr += "</tr>";
t += tr; }
  if (notas[i] > 38) {
var tr = "<tr>";
tr += "<td>"+notasid[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td style='backgroud: green ;'>"+notas[i]+"</td>";
tr += "<td>"+notasr[i]+"</td>";
tr += "</tr>";
t += tr; }}
```

Comment: i'm sure if you tried you could come up with something that doesn't duplicate so much code. the only thing that needs to be changed is the background color.

Comment: set a variable for the background color. change teh variable depending on the number, then insert the variable into the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data attributes to each row, and target the rows with css. Just make 3 versions of the data-attribute, one for less than 38, one for equal to, and one for greater.

Comment: why is a data attribute better than simply using a class?

Comment: I would agree with you if CSS had numeric equality/inequality selectors, but alas, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
var tr = "<tr>";
```

you can put you css class

```
var tr = "<tr class='" + (notas[i] < 38 ? "red" : (notas[i]==38 ? "blue" : "green")) +"'>"
```

and you should define thoses 3 classes in your css

```
.red{
// style while < 38
}

.blue{
// style while == 38
}

.green{
// style otherwise
}
```

Comment: please explain how this works, don't just provide code. ideally you could link to something that explains ternary.

Comment: I used in this code a short if syntax ( condition ? instruction if true: instruction if false)
in your case, 
if notas[i] < 38 then tr will contain <tr class="red">

if notas[i] == 38 then tr will contain <tr class="blue">
otherwise then tr will contain <tr class="green">
and you should define those three classes in your css file

Comment: i see that, it's called [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). you should explain how it works. just providing code isn't helpful to future visitors.

Comment: I used in this code a short if syntax ( condition ? instruction if true: instruction if false)
in your case, 
if notas[i] < 38 then tr will contain <tr class="red">

if notas[i] == 38 then tr will contain <tr class="blue">
otherwise then tr will contain <tr class="green">
and you should define those three classes in your css file

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var t = "";
for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {

    let bgColor = null;
    if (notas[i] < 38) bgColor = "red";
    else if (notas[i] === 38) bgColor = "blue";
    else bgColor = "green";

    var tr = "<tr style='background-color:" + bgColor + "'>";
    tr += "<td>" + notasid[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + notas[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + notasr[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "</tr>";
    t += tr;
}
```

With classes and css file/not embedded:

```
var t = "";
for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {

    let bgColor = null;
    if (notas[i] < 38) bgColor = "red";
    else if (notas[i] === 38) bgColor = "blue";
    else bgColor = "green";

    var tr = "<tr class='" + bgColor + "'>";
    tr += "<td>" + notasid[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + notas[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + notasr[i] + "</td>";
    tr += "</tr>";
    t += tr;
}
```

CSS:

```
.red{
   background-color: red
 }

.blue{
   background-color: blue
 }

.green{
   background-color: green
 }
```

Comment: it's enclosed, there's no opportunity for user input to be inserted, therefore no xss vulnerability.

Comment: it worked! thaaanks! i need to do something to set the background from the css (they are asking me to do it that way) do you know how? if u dont, i will use this solution, is almost perfect! :)

Comment: Yes ill edit it to show you how to use css with classes but someone already answered that way below I think. @MohamedKallel

Comment: @TomásElgueta that *is* css. anything inside a `style` attribute is css.

Comment: And yes that is css already I think hes asking about not embedded in the html

Comment: yep, i was asking about using css apart from the html, but this works too hehe thanks!

Comment: Edited, test it out

Comment: Please note that if you ever decide to pull data from an external data source instead of using hard-coded arrays, [XSS](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting) does become a concern.

Comment: Yes but in this case it's hard coded, I think he is just starting out with some exercises for classes or something, if it is that way he will learn in the future all of that I hope.

Comment: Yep, that right hehe just practice. i dont know why  but the second one is not working

Comment: Did you put it in a separate css file? If so, did you import that file in your html?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `innerHTML`, you should create new DOM elements for each item you intend to add to the page, then use `innerText` to fill them with your desired content.

If you ever choose to switch from hard-coded data in arrays to an external data source, you should refactor your code to use `innerText`, as `innerHTML` could allow a malicious user to insert arbitrary (and potentially harmful) code into your page. `innerText` will automatically escape the content you pass it, mitigating this risk.

```js
const notas = [38, 43, 99, 97, 29, 29, 0, 100, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 37, 39, ];
const notasid = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

let notasr = notas.map((num) => {
  const remainder = num % 5;
  if (num < 38) {
    return num;
  } else if (remainder >= 3) {
    num += 5 - remainder;
  }
  return num;
});

var t = "";
for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
  let val = notas[i];
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  let cell = document.createElement("td");
  row.classList.add((val < 38 ? 'red' : (val == 38 ? 'blue' : 'green')));
  let id = cell.cloneNode(),
    v = cell.cloneNode(),
    r = cell.cloneNode();
  id.innerText = notasid[i];
  row.appendChild(id);
  v.innerText = notas[i];
  row.appendChild(v);
  r.innerText = notasr[i];
  row.appendChild(r);
  document.getElementById("posts").appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="wp-table" id="posts">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nota Original </th>
    <th>Nota Redondeada</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is functional, so I'm not quite sure why downvotes are warranted.

Comment: the string being inserted is completely independent from user input. an xss attack requires user input. i didn't downvote becuase the code isn't functional, i donwvoted because your explanation is wrong. (there is absolutely no xss vulnerability here)

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Fair enough. Explanation removed. I will point out, though, that if external data is *ever* used, code employing `innerHTML` *will* expose an XSS vulnerability.